# Partial CellFeed load

Tags: google-sheets, cells

Happy new year, folks,

Currently, I'm accessing and loading a Google Sheets worksheet using the following, default way:

```
URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
URL cellFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0)).getCellFeedUrl();

// Get entries as cells
feed = (CellFeed) service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
```

Then I work with it, etc. Everyting works just fine.

### The problem:

I'm about to deploy the application and have it work with a Worksheet that has several hundred, if not thousand rows of cells. To me, **the only relevant rows are usually the 100-200 bottom ones**.

Is there a way to partially load a CellFeed, preferrably from the bottom up? Does the API provide such a way?

Comment: Please clarify. Your sample code is not google-apps-script yet you tagged it as such. There is already an apps script answer. If that's not what you need I can provide another answer that does it directly with the spreadsheet api.

Comment: @ZigMandel Yes, I am using the Java g-spreadsheets API. The tag was edited out.

Comment: @ZigMandel I would really appreciate an answer that does it directly in the java spreadsheets API

Comment: Ill add an answer soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API itself, you can do it with cell feed or list feed.
in cell feed, look at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#fetching_specific_rows_or_columns 
you can specify there the minimum/maximum row/columns to get, and there is also a java example in there.
a more efficient way to get your data, is the row feed as it sends less bytes in return:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/
with the undocumented "start-index' parameter so it only reads starting at that row.
I use this and works for the "old" and "new" sheets.
The first time you will need to get all rows (or attempt some sort of binary lookup to find the last spreadsheet row).
I have not used the java api library, it probably does not allow for that undocumented parameter. You can always do a url "get" directly from java or any language and use the spreadsheet api directly by https.
I got this tip a long time ago from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-spreadsheets-api/dSniiF18xnM
and use it on this github project (javascript ajax call example)
https://github.com/zmandel/Plus-for-Trello/blob/master/source/sql.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any CellFeed, but you can create an HTML feed that retrieves a number of ROWS from any Spreadsheet, then treat that HTML, would that work for you? What are the goals when retrieving the information?
Eg.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form").evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function getLastLines( numLines, ssId, sheetName ){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return JSON.stringify(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - numLines, 1, numLines, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues());
}
```

in form.html

```
<div id="arrayPlace"></div>
<script>
function changeDiv( res ){
    document.getElementById("arrayPlace").innerHTML = res;
}

function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

var numLines = getUrlParameter("numLines");
var ssId = getUrlParameter("ssId");
var sheetName = getUrlParameter("sheetName");

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( changeDiv ).getLastLines( numLines, ssId, sheetName );
</script>
```

And the URL would have the additional parameters:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFLN-qqTcXXAVgR-aDa9h61yTa39kVhE2MwX9htRbIm2NN5I4/exec?numLines=5&ssId=1dJlNmtvcsWixEDnUz7GxnyLMZKXHwA-9uopYPUC8I4E&sheetName=Sheet1